# Unable to convert word with emf images into Html using docx4j

Tags: docx4j

I have tried converting the docx (word) documents into Html using docx4j. It works fine if the images are png or jpg, however when the image type is emf, the images does not render (or gets converted) into html. Any alternative solutions is much appreciated!!
Thank you

Comment: See https://www.docx4java.org/forums/docx-java-f6/need-support-to-handle-emf-wmf-images-t264.html

Comment: i dont see any solution there. Thank you.